# How to draw relplot with boxplot then only frequencies specified in seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Let we have such data:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = np.array([[5.2, 500, 1], [7.2, 450, 1],[6.2, 350, 1],[4.6, 400,1 ],[5.9, 212,1], [6.2, 350, 2],[4.6, 400,2 ],[5.9, 212,2]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':data[:,0],'size':data[:,1], 'time':data[:,2]})
```

[image]

`val` - actual mean value, which were calculated from dataset with size specified in `size` column

Drawing boxplot:

```
ax = sns.boxplot (x = 'time', y="val", data=df)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x = 'time', y="val", data=df, color=".25", size = df.size )
```

[image]

it will draw obviously without taking into account real mean - which should sum of `val` divided by sum of `size` for each `time` (why all dots are with the same size)

Drawing `relplot` help to draws sizes of dots with proper size, but how to draw there true boxplot:

```
ax = sns.relplot(x = 'time', y="val",  size="size",dashes = True,
            sizes=(40, 400), alpha=.5, palette="muted",
            height=6, data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have seaborn 0.9.0 to test this directly, but from what I read [from the documentation `sns.relplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) returns a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid), while [`sns.boxplot` is an axes level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot) (meaning it will use whatever Axes instance you choose). That means that you should be able to do something like this:

```
g = sns.relplot(x = 'time', y="val", data=df, size="size")
ax = sns.boxplot (x = 'time', y="val", data=df, ax=g.axes[0,0])  # <-
```